# Computer is telling me, "Not connected - No connections are available" Despite the fact I am connected to the internet?

Tags: windows-8.1, internet, ethernet, wired

Just got a new PSU because my old one was on the way out.
Started up my computer and everything works fine except for a yellow triangle with a warning tick on the Network and Sharing center icon on my task bar.

The network adapter looks like this:

[image]

The device manager looks like this:

[image]

Ethernet adapter IP/DNS settings:

[image]

Some how I am connected to the internet though, any help would be appreciated.

I have already deleted and reinstalled drivers for the device, rebooted my PC, rebooted my router, reset my modem, turned my PC on and off and taken my Ethernet cable out and put it back in.

Comment: What are the current IP settings you're using for that network connection?

Comment: Check to make sure your Ethernet adapter has the setting to auto discover IP address (DHCP) and DNS servers as this may be why Windows can't work out if it's connected.

Comment: Try setting the DNS to be obtained from your router (the "auto" one above where you've put the Google DNS)

Comment: It appears that you have created two accounts, possibly by using a multiple computers or browsers without first logging in or creating an account.  You can instead [register](https://superuser.com/users/signup) an account. You should use the [contact form](http://superuser.com/contact) and select "I need to merge accounts" in order to merge your accounts.  For your information the accounts you have created are http://superuser.com/users/611221/user611221 and http://superuser.com/users/611225/user611225.  This will allow you to edit your question and potentially accept answers to this question.

Answer (score 1):

A yellow triangle means that your drivers and hardware are working properly.

The problem is with the IP, your PC is not able to obtain an IP address to assess internet.

You can check it by opening cmd and type **ipconfig** command and hit enter.

Check for ip v4 address as well as v6.
If they exists then it's ok. Otherwise type **ipconfig /renew or /release** to obtain a new one.

If it doesn't work turn off router and connect the Ethernet cable in the same port as it as before the maintenance.

Leave it for few minutes and turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

Some options you should check:

1. Verify there is a DHCP server on the same physical network as your computer (usually, the router on home networks)
2. Check if this DHCP server is active and has spare IPs to distribute (should be in the DHCP settings of your router, can't help you there)
3. If the DHCP is enabled, open a command prompt and run the commands @Rohitkr suggested.
4. If DHCP is **not** enabled, or not working, check "Use the following IP address" in your IPv4 settings and manually enter the IP you want to give to your computer, as well as its subnet mask (usually `255.255.255.0`) and it default gateway (the router's IP in this subnet).
5. Do point 4 if there is no DHCP at all on this network.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue may be broken registry permissions.

To fix:

1. Run regedit.exe.
2. To `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList`'s ACL, add `NT Service\netprofm` and grant it all rights except Write DAC and Write Owner. Check the "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object" checkbox.
3. To `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Nla`'s ACL, add `NT Service\NlaSvc` and grant it the same rights as in step 1.

Alternatively, you may use [SetACL](https://helgeklein.com/setacl/):

```
setacl.exe -ot reg -on "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList" -actn ace -ace "n:NT Service\netprofm;p:query_val,set_val,create_subkey,enum_subkeys,notify,create_link,delete,read_access" -actn rstchldrn -rst dacl
setacl.exe -ot reg -on "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Nla" -actn ace -ace "n:NT Service\NlaSvc;p:query_val,set_val,create_subkey,enum_subkeys,notify,create_link,delete,read_access"
```

Then log off and log on again.

Tested on Windows 7.